# Migrating from Akka Http to Http4s - custom directives

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http, http4s

I'm starting to learn Http4s, at work we may need to migrate Rest APIs implemented with Akka Http to Http4s.

As an example I can define a custom directive like this:

```scala
trait CustomDirectives {

  def extractUUID: Directive1[UUID] = {
    path(Segment).flatMap { maybeuuid =>
      Try(UUID.fromString(maybeuuid)) match {
        case Success(result) => provide(result)
        case Failure(_) =>
          complete(StatusCodes.BadRequest, s"Invalid uuid: $maybeuuid")
      }
    }
  }

}
```

So everytime I want to extract an UUID and validate it I can use this directive.
We have other custom directives to make some processing on headers, and many more.

Is there anything similar to akka custom directives but in Http4s?

Comment: I suggest migrating from Akka HTTP DSL to e.g. Tapir first (1.0 released today!), and then swapping the interpreter. It will be so much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is described in [Handling Path Parameters](https://http4s.org/v0.23/docs/dsl.html#handling-path-parameters) section of the documentation

```
// standard Scala extractor, matching String against UUID
object UUIDVar {
  def unapply(maybeuuid: String): Option[UUID] =
    Try(UUID.fromString(maybeuuid)).toOption
}

val usersService = HttpRoutes.of[IO] {
  // just use extractor in pattern matching
  case GET -> Root / "users" / UUIDVar(uuid) =>
    Ok(useUUIDForSth(uuid))
}
```

However, personally, I find it easier to describe endpoints with libraries like [Tapir](https://tapir.softwaremill.com/en/latest/index.html) or [Endpoint4s](https://endpoints4s.github.io/) since their DSL seem more intuitive to me and I am not coupling my code with a particular implementation.